# Why are you allowed to do a u-substitution on an integral with complex numbers with infinite bounds?

Tags: integration, complex-numbers, substitution

Consider the following integral:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}f(ix)dx$$

And consider a scenario where the following u-sub would be appropriate to solve the integral:

$u = ix, du=idx$

$$=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{i}f(u)du$$

Why is this u-substitution allowed? I understand how you can change the lower bound, because $0\times i=0.$ However.... leaving the upper bound at $\infty$ is bothersome to me. It should intuitively make sense that $\infty$ times any positive number is $\infty$. Maybe we can... just extend this rule to complex numbers? I'm aware of an example in which this is used, but I have NO idea the justification. You're really making the claim that $\infty \times i=\infty.$ Can we always do this? What if our complex number was $-1-i$?

Edit: To clarify, I will provide the example. The integral is:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x^2} \cos (x^2)dx$$

Transform it as follows:

$$\text{Re}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{(-1+i)x^2}dx$$

The substitution is $u=\sqrt{-1+i}x$ to transform this into a Gaussian integral. How do we justify the bounds from this point being $0$ and $\infty$? Are we saying that $\sqrt{-1+i}\times\infty = \infty$? Does the fact that we're only taking the real part have anything to do with this?

Comment: "I'm aware of an example in which this is used" Could you edit your question to state it, or even discuss it alone? If a trick doesn't seem like it would work in general, maybe a second fact makes it work in a given context.

Comment: Edited, @J.G. Thanks.

Comment: It seems to me that the upper limit is usually written as $i\infty$ meaning that the path of integration is the positive $y$-axis.  With move complicated substitutions it's usually written as a line integral, with a separate statement as to the path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $I$ is given by

$$I=\int_0^\infty f(ix)\,dx$$

then the substitution $x\to -i y$ gives

$$I=-i \int_0^{i\infty}f(y)\,dy$$

It is ***not*** true, in general, that $I=-i \int_0^{\infty}f(y)\,dy$.

---

If $f(z)$ is, however, analytic in the first quadrant of the $z$-plane, and decays sufficiently rapidly such that

$$\lim_{R\to \infty}\int_0^{\pi/2}f(Re^{i\phi})\,iRe^{i\phi}\,d\phi=0$$

then Cauchy's Integral Theorem guarantees that

$$\int_0^{iR} f(x)\,dx+\int_{\pi /2}^0 f(Re^{i\phi})\,iRe^{i\phi}\,d\phi+\int_{R}^0 f(y)\,dy=0$$

which after letting $R\to\infty$, we find that

$$\int_0^{i\infty} f(x)\,dx=\int_0^\infty f(y)\,dy$$